# Perl Array Reference with hash reference

Tags: perl

```
my $var1=[{'a'=>'1','b'=>'2'},1];

print @$var1[0]->{a};
```

it will print 1

but, if i print like below:

```
print @$var1->{a};
```

it will print error like below

```
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference;
```

Can anyone explain diff between both print statement?

Comment: The only way you can access `a` is through element `0` of the array. Not sure what you expected of the second print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my $var1=[{'a'=>'1','b'=>'2'},1];
```

$var1 is array reference which contains hash reference at index 0 and scalar at index 1

to derefer $var1 to array, we have to use @$var1.(which gives the 2-element array)
And for accessing single element we have to use $$var1[0] or $var1->[0].

And again $var1->[0] is a hash reference. 
To derefer it, we have to use $var1->[0]{'a'}.

But the statement "@$var1->{'a'}" is invalid, since

1. Hash reference is present at 0 index of the array "@$var1".
2. All references are scalar, Array cannot be used to derefer at hash reference.

For more information, please refer

1. [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
2. [Bless my Referents](http://www.perl.com/pub/1999/09/refererents.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
@$var1[0]->{a}
```

is usually written as

```
$var1->[0]{a}
```

The second syntax, though, is different.

```
@$var1->{a}
```

is equivalent to

```
@{$var1}->{a};
```

You can't dereference an array (`@{$var1}`) as a hash. Another question is why `undef` is reported, to which I don't know the answer.

Comment: Note: @{$var1}->{a} should be equivalent to "0"->{a}, but it's not. It produces really odd code instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the first statement you print the value of key 'a' of the first element in your array (which is $var1)
In the second statement you print the value of key 'a' of your array (and get an error as array doesn't have keys)

Hope this helps